# Getting "( unexpected" syntax error - Script works in one instance but not another

Tags: bash, select, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Select an install package: "
items=("Essentials - VLC"
       "Graphics Suite - Inkscape, GIMP, Blender"
       "Streaming Suite - OBS, Openshot, Blender")
select opt in "${items[@]}" "Cancel - Install Manually"
do
    case $opt in
        1) echo "== Installing Essentials ==";
           sudo apt install vlc -y; wait; break;;
        2) echo "== Installing Graphics Suite ==";
           sudo apt install vlc inkscape gimp blender -y; wait; break;;
        3) echo "== Installing Streaming Suite ==";
           sudo apt install vlc obs openshot blender -y; wait; break;;
        $((${#items[@]}+1)))
           echo "Remember, you can manually install with";
           echo "  'sudo apt install [app name]'";
           echo "  'sudo flatpak install [app name]'";
           echo "or through the 'Software Manager'";
           sleep 8; break;;
        *) echo "Invalid option - please select a number from 1 to $((${#items[@]}+1))";
    esac
done
clear
```

I'm experimenting with an item `select` command. When I open the script as an executable and it opens a terminal window *(top example)*, the script runs as expected. But when I open the Terminal and run the script with a `sh` command *(bottom example)*, I get an `"(" unexpected` syntax error on line 42 and the script breaks.

What's going on here?

```
# Line 42 lands on the options tab.

options=("Essentials - VLC"\
         "Graphics Suite - Inkscape, GIMP, Blender"\
         "Streaming Suite - OBS, Openshot, Blender")
```

I also tried it on a single line (without the backslashes) but got the same error result when I tried to run it from the Terminal with `sh`.

EDIT: I tried running it with `bash` and it ran without breaking, but now it gives me the else condition: `*) echo "Invalid option...` no matter which option I pick.

Comment: You wrote your script for bash, so it must be run by bash and not by sh.

Comment: Okay. This time I used the 'bash' command to run it and that pesky error didn't reappear, but now no matter which number I input, I always get the else "*)" condition: "Invalid option - select..."

Comment: Show the code (not a screenshot). Show how you call the script. Post the complete error message.

Comment: Screenshot removed; relevant code added

Comment: Add `declare -p opt >&2` to log what value `opt` has before you enter your `case`.

Comment: What you'll see is something like `declare -- opt="Graphics Suite - Inkscape, GIMP, Blender"` -- it's not putting the "2" in the variable but the option that the 2 refers to. If you don't want that, you shouldn't be using `select`.

Comment: I suggest that you read the bash man-page, in particular about the `selectcommand (`select name ...`). It says: _If the line consists of a number corresponding to one of the displayed words, then the value of name is set  to  **that  word**._

Answer (score 1):

`sh` aka `POSIX` shell, don't have array feature. Choose if you want to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [sh](/questions/tagged/sh).

`bash` support array and even, associative arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

options=(
    "Essentials - VLC"
    "Graphics Suite - Inkscape, GIMP, Blender"
    "Streaming Suite - OBS, Openshot, Blender"
)

select x in "${options[@]}"; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

```
1) Essentials - VLC
2) Graphics Suite - Inkscape, GIMP, Blender
3) Streaming Suite - OBS, Openshot, Blender
#?
```